# Bundle using old version of jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundler

I am trying to preview a site I have built in the past, using jekyll. Since then, I believe there have been updates to jekyll, and I now use `zsh` on MacOS 10.15.2. I'm having trouble now running a preview because it seems `bundle` keeps using an old version of `jekyll`.

When I run `bundle exec jekyll server --unpublished` I receive this error:

```
(base) ➜  angoodkind.github.io git:(master) ✗ bundle exec jekyll server --unpublished
Configuration file: /Users/adamg/Dropbox/Website/github_io/angoodkind.github.io/_config.yml
NOTE: Inheriting Faraday::Error::ClientError is deprecated; use Faraday::ClientError instead. It will be removed in or after version 1.0
Faraday::Error::ClientError.inherited called from /Users/adamg/Dropbox/Website/github_io/angoodkind.github.io/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/octokit-4.14.0/lib/octokit/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:14.
            Source: /Users/adamg/Dropbox/Website/github_io/angoodkind.github.io
       Destination: /Users/adamg/Dropbox/Website/github_io/angoodkind.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
Error reading file /Users/adamg/Dropbox/Website/github_io/angoodkind.github.io/blog/index.html: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 7 column 5
             Error: could not read file /Users/adamg/Dropbox/Website/github_io/angoodkind.github.io/vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb: Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter.
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    Invalid date '<%= Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z') %>': Document 'vendor/cache/ruby/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/site_template/_posts/0000-00-00-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown.erb' does not have a valid date in the YAML front matter.
```

However, the system should be using jekyll 4.0.0, which was recently installed. Why is it using jekyll 3.5.2?

Comment: What’s in your `Gemfile`? The primary purpose of `bundle exec` is to run a program with only those gems in scope, so if the file lists an old version that is the one that will be used, regardless of what else is installed.

Comment: I can see from your [Gemfile.lock](https://github.com/angoodkind/angoodkind.github.io/blob/master/Gemfile.lock) that it’s still referencing 3.5.2. `bundle update` can help you with that.